# javascript find image index

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to make the url in the `data.artist.image` array show up so i can put it in an image tag later. i keep getting [object][object] in the console. WHY `data.artist.image[0]` not giving me the first item in the array (the url for the small image) here's the object and the code:

```
Object {artist: Object}
artist: Object
bandmembers: Object
bio: Object
image: Array[5]
 mbid: "0acae232-d31a-4211-b6d0-6af1b6350274"
name: "Thursday"
ontour: "0"
similar: Object
stats: Object
streamable: "1"
tags: Object
url: "http://www.last.fm/music/Thursday"
```

code: all the ajax works. i'm just not doing something right to the array.

```
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",       
      url: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getInfo&artist=Thursday&api_key=0bd6c5780da878f5bb51393e84329809&format=json&callback=?",
      //data: (optional) and not used here
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);          
        var html = "";
        //var artist = data.artist;

        html =  
                '<p>' + data.artist.image[0] + '</p>' +
                '<p>' + data.artist.name + '</p>' +
                '<p>' + data.artist.bio.content + '</p>';
        $("#content").append(html);

      },
      complete: function(){
        console.log("call is complete!");
      },
      error: function(){
        console.log("something went wrong!");
      }
    });
```

Comment: I think it is `data.image[0]`

Comment: no that's what was already included in the code and wasn't working for me. thanks for answering my question though. i appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

image[0] will give you the first object in that array, but its still an object not a string value

```
data.artist.image[0]["#text"] // "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/59393737.png"
```

to get the url of the image, you may want to have a check that data.artist.image[0] is actually a value and not null/undefined.

Comment: thanks! as i was waiting i did realize i need to use #text, but was still messing up the syntax. i knew it was a syntax issue, but i just couldn't get it. thanks for the help!